# Jquery: bind load + change simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery

In many cases, I need to bind a behaviour to an element after loading, and then after an event triggering (like "change").
I think the best way would be to make it in the same line:

```
$('#element_id').bind('load, change', function () {
...
});
```

But this works only for "change" and not for "load". There is a better way?

Comment: I removed the comma, but it doesn't work anyway. I think there would be some limitations with load

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I stumbled across the same problem. Removing comma is not enough, at least not in this case:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#element_id').bind('load change', function () {
        ... // (this DOESN'T get called on page load)
    });
});
```

I guess `load` events get triggered before `$(document).ready()`.

This is a simple solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#element_id').bind('change', function () {
        ...
    });
    $('#element_id').trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: Even this will loop the change event a billion times. No idea why. I tried this method and others and it just keeps wanting to loop.

Comment: Are you triggering the event inside the function? It shouldn't loop, there must be an error somewhere. You can try making a minimal error case and posting code in a separate question; most likely you will figure it out before hitting "Post" button. :)

Comment: Not triggering it inside the function.     $('#employeeDropDown').on('change', function (event) {
        var form = $(event.target).parents("form");
        form.submit();
    }).trigger('change'); or even as you put it above, will cause it to loop.

Comment: I think you are - `form.submit()` probably triggers change event too. Use `console.log()` (or JavaScript debugger if you like) to see which part is looping. But really, this has nothing to do with this question, you should post your own. I can assure you there is nothing in the answer above which would make it loop - I use it frequently and it works.

Comment: Bind is deprecated since jQuery 3.0, but this still works perfectly (just replace `bind` with `on` then call `trigger`. Also, this is the "correct" way to call this according to the documentation now, not sure what it read back in 2011. Calling `load` on a `ready` event is considered unsafe and will not run when scripts are loaded dynamically. See: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Easier: $('selector').on('change',function(){ ... }).trigger('change');

Answer (score 10):

For already loaded content, when you want to run a function on an event and also straight away, you can use a custom event of your own naming to avoid triggering any existing bindings from libraries etc. on the built in events, e.g.

```
$(".my-selector").on("change rightnow", function() {
  // do stuff...
}).triggerHandler("rightnow");
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't you just need to remove the comma?

Answer (score 1):

try it without the comma:

```
$('#element_id').bind('load change', function () {
...
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/bind/#multiple-events