# After Populating a Select2 Dropdown List How Can I Force the Element Title to remain Displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

On page load, I populate a Select2 `Select->Option` list and I bind the `change` event using the technique here [Jquery: bind load + change simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531347/jquery-bind-load-change-simultaneously)
 so that I can control the change event to load other information.  Now, this all works well except that, and this is the problem.

After populating the `Select->Option` list with the function `fillProjectSelect();` the first option in the list appears as the default text which means that a change event on the item that is shown **will not** trigger because it is not a change.  Naturally, this causes a great deal of confusion.

So the question is how can I force the Select2 option text to display the list title, which happens to be `Select a Project` and not the first element in the list?

*Here is a code fragment:*

```
fillProjectSelect();
$( "#projectSelector" ).bind ('change', function () {
    var val = $("#projectSelector").val();
     $( "#project_description" ).text( projectData[val].description );
     $( "#contract_sum" ).text( projectData[val].contract_sum );
     $( "#percentage_fee" ).text( projectData[val].percentage_fee );
     $( "#fee" ).text( projectData[val].fee );
     var project_ID = projectData[val].project_ID;
     etc...
   })
```

Just in case it is helpful, I have also added the `fillProjectSelect()` code.

```
        function fillProjectSelect() {
        var projectIndex = 0;
        getProjectData(function(data) {
        console.log(data)
         var combo = $(".myselect")[projectIndex];
         for (var i = 0; i <  data.projectData.length; i++) {
            projectData[i] = data.projectData[i];
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.setAttribute("value",i);
         //  option.setAttribute("selected",true);
            option.innerHTML=projectData[i].name;
            combo.appendChild(option);
         }
     });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is interested, there is a bit of a hack that appears to work.  What you do is set the first element's value to -1 and the option text to  "Pick a Project" and then then remove it during the click event with

```
$(".myselect option[value='-1']").each(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```