# disable woocommerce place order button if custom select field is not selected

Tags: php, html, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have added select custom field to woocommerce checkout page :

```
// Add custom checkout datepicker field
 
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'checkout_display_datepicker_custom_field' );
function checkout_display_datepicker_custom_field( $checkout ) {
    
    echo '<div id="datepicker-wrapper" style="width:50%;">';
    
       $field_id = 'my_datepicker';
       $today = strtotime('today');
       $tomorrow = strtotime('tomorrow');
    
     woocommerce_form_field(  $field_id, array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
        'label' => __('Delivery Date'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Select Delivery Date'),
        'required' => true, // Or false
        'onchange' => 'ValidateDropDwon(this)',
        'options'     => array(
            '' => '',
            date(('d F Y'), $today ) => date(('d F Y'), $today ),
            date(('d F Y'), $tomorrow ) => date(('d F Y'), $tomorrow ),
        )));

     echo '<br></div>';
     
    
}
```

and used this jQuery to check if one item of select field is selected and then enable "Place Order" button:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function(){
function ValidateDropDwon(dd){
  var input = document.getElementById('place_order')
  if(dd.value == '') input.disabled = true; else input.disabled = false;
}

});
```

but it doesn't work and "Place Order" button is always active! I really don't have any idea why it doesn't work!?

Comment: have you debug from console ? add console.log('ValidateDropDwon') inside function ValidateDropDwon, and reload your page, is your function already called ?

Comment: @LexaVey I tried console.log('ValidateDropDwon') but nothing special appears in console, how can I call the function already?

Comment: then check your php output of checkout_display_datepicker_custom_field function, can you send to me the output ? paste into pastebin.com or etc

Comment: @LexaVey Please kindly check these urls: 1) https://pastebin.com/gwSbdHx0  2) https://pastebin.com/aB5nJK5A

Comment: i found solution your problem, before answer your question, i wanna make sure your problem has been solved, kindly check my snippet on https://jsfiddle.net/lexavey/t9oj43g6/26/

Comment: @LexaVey Your sample code is exactly my desire; I tried your JS code in my page but still it doesn't work. In console I have this error: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> $('#my_datepicker').bind('change', function ()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226673/discussion-between-lexa-vey-and-omid-toraby).

Comment: @LexaVey I had gotten a new issue about calling event which is described  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65789631/4170774) and fortunately solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Make sure function is called

Add `console.log('Im call ValidateDropDwon')` inside function `ValidateDropDwon` then reload your page.

Ex :

```
function ValidateDropDwon(dd){
  console.log('Im call ValidateDropDwon')
  var input = document.getElementById('place_order')
  if(dd.value == '') input.disabled = true; else input.disabled = false;
}
```

Press **F12** to open your browser console and see is `Im call ValidateDropDwon`showing in browser console.

Based on your problem, function `ValidateDropDwon` is not called.

## Check HTML output

Let we check in HTML output of PHP

### Datepicker output

```
<div id="datepicker-wrapper" style="width:50%;">
   <p class="form-row form-row-wide validate-required" id="my_datepicker_field" data-priority="">
      <label for="my_datepicker" class=""> Delivery Date &nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="required" aria-required="true">*</abbr></label>
      <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
         <select name="my_datepicker" id="my_datepicker" class="select select2-hidden-accessible enhanced" data-allow_clear="true" data-placeholder=" Delivery Date & Time" required="required" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" aria-required="true">
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="1">31-Dec-2020 From 13 to 17</option>
            <option value="2">01 Jan 2021 From 13 to 17</option>
         </select>
         <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="rtl" style="width: auto;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-my_datepicker-container" role="combobox"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-my_datepicker-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true"><span class="select2-selection__placeholder"> Delivery Date & Time</span></span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
      </span>
   </p>
   <br>
</div>
```

### Place order button output

```
<button type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="Place Order" data-value="Place Order"> Place Order</button>
<ul role="menu" aria-label="Pagination">
   <li class="" aria-disabled="false" style=""><a href="#previous" role="menuitem">Previous</a></li>
   <li aria-hidden="true" aria-disabled="true" class="disabled" style="display: none;"><a href="#next" role="menuitem" style="outline: none;">Next</a></li>
   <li aria-hidden="false" style=""><a href="#finish" role="menuitem" class="finish-btn">Place Order</a></li>
</ul>
```

See, your PHP have `'onchange' => 'ValidateDropDwon(this)',` but attribute `onchange` is not exist in select with id `my_datepicker`

So the problem is in PHP not showing onchange atribute after execution, also button html is not disabled by default, there many way to fix this problem, fix from PHP, fix from HTML, fix from JavaScript.

I will explain fix from JavaScript

## Fix from JavaScript

Create javascript event on change

```
$('#my_datepicker').change(function () { ... }
```

this event is working, but now we have new problem, because button is not *disabled by default*, we need disable button first while page load, we can use on `load` event to disable button, but we can combine event `load` and `change` with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531347/jquery-bind-load-change-simultaneously) solution

I'm use jQuery 3.4.1

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#my_datepicker').bind('change', function () {
        if($(this).val() != ''){ // if value is not empty, enable button
          $("#place_order").attr("disabled", false);
        }else{
            $("#place_order").attr("disabled", true); // if empty disable button
        }
    });
    $('#my_datepicker').trigger('change'); // event `change` on page `load`
});
```

Check https://jsfiddle.net/lexavey/t9oj43g6/26/ working code.