# jQuery bind method does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, woocommerce, bind

I need to perform different actions for a select dropdown if it is selected or not! I tried this code which is working correctly in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omid020/ntro48xg/), but it doesn't work within my project which is a checkout form of WooCommerce:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#my_datepicker").bind('change', function() {
    if (jQuery(this).val() != "select") {
      alert('Something is selected!');
    } else {
      alert('Nothing is selected!');
    }
  });

  jQuery("#my_datepicker").trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="my_datepicker" id="my_datepicker" class="select valid" data-placeholder="Please select" aria-invalid="false">
  <option value="select">Please select</option>
  <option value="11th December">11th December</option>
  <option value="12th December">12th December</option>
</select>
```

In my project `alert('Nothing is selected!');` works on page load as expected but after changing select options nothing happens! Even when I choose `<option value="select">Please select</option>` again, it's related alert does not appear. Can you please guide me about this issue?

Comment: Check the console for errors in your local version. Also note that `bind()` is very old, has been deprecated and will likely be removed in the next version of jQuery. You should replace it with [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on) instead.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have no error in Console. Also tried on() but with same result.

Comment: @freedomn-m I have placed that script in footer area; Is there any solution to set a better priority?

Comment: I'd suggest changing it to a delegated event, incase the HTML is being rebuilt by woocomerce or wordpress.  Change `jQuery("#my_datepicker").bind('change', function() {` to `jQuery(document).on("change", "#my_datepicker", function() {`

Answer (score 0):

Check I hope it's working but If this code not working,
it means js error coming on your site that's why the js code block below is error generating.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#my_datepicker").trigger('change');
});
jQuery(document).on('change',"#my_datepicker", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (jQuery(this).val() !== "select") {
      alert('Something is selected!');
    } else {
      alert('Nothing is selected!');
    }
});
</script>
<select name="my_datepicker" id="my_datepicker" class="select valid" data-placeholder="Please select" aria-invalid="false">
  <option value="select">Please select</option>
  <option value="11th December">11th December</option>
  <option value="12th December">12th December</option>
</select>
```